# AI incorrectly grouping paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, line-art

I am very new to Adobe Illustrator and am attempting to make a logo.  For some reason it seems like the program is linking items together that I do NOT want linked.  I cannot ungroup them, and when I try to move or adjust 1 thing, all the others are effected.

How do i prevent this from occurring?  I have included a screenshot showing the linking behavior.  I would like each of those shapes to be treated independently.

[image: bad linking]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Jeremy what is going on is that you are painting whit "live painting" i know that because se little stars on the corners, it doest let the objects ungroup, you need to release the "live painting", Selecting the group and going (object) -> (live paainting) -> (release) and now the objects are free each one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the object(s), right click and select ungroup.

[image: ungroup]

Other things to remember

- You might have selected the layer instead of the object itself.
- If you have a clipping mask, everything will move together just like if the objects were grouped together.

Comment: I've tried that and nothing changes.  It still links them all together.  There is also a big blue box that surrounds all the items such that if i drag in a side, all objects change respectively.   Any other ideas?

Comment: @JeremyThomas See if my edit suggestions help.

Comment: I think it has to do with copy and pasting.   I only have the issue when part of the new object has been copied from an existing one.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @JeremyThomas I don't really understand what you mean by "part of the new object has been copied". Besides them being grouped, selecting the layer or in a clipping mask I am not sure what is going on. I have never seen an image selection where the outside boxes have a star in them. I would suggest asking in the Adobe Illustrator Forum.